# Find positions in which list elements are equal

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have 2 lists of 10000+ lists of 3 numbers, e.g.

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},...}
{{2,1,3},{4,5,6},{41,2,0},...}
```

Wanting a result like

```
{2,...}
```

Getting some sort of list of `True`/`False` is also probably enough, like this:

```
{False,True,False,...}
```

I guess I could use `Position` once I've done that.

I tried to use `Thread`, as below:

```
Thread[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} == {{a, b}, {d, e}, {f, e}}]
```

which gives the `True`/`False` output

```
{True, {c, d} == {d, e}, {e, f} == {f, e}}
```

But as soon as there are actual numbers in place, it doesn't work:

```
Thread[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}} == {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
```

Returns

```
False
```

I'd really appreciate any help you could give.

Thanks,

H

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible way of doing it:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
b = {{2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {41, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}};
Position[MapThread[Equal, {a, b}], True]
```

The output reads:  `{{2}, {4}}`

In my code, it compares the elements for each position, but it doesn't "cross check" them, i.e.it doesn't consider that the element n of list a could be equal to element m!=n of list b

EDIT:
note that the solution provided by @Henrik Schumacher is much faster :)

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {100000, 3}];
b = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {100000, 3}];

RepeatedTiming@Position[MapThread[Equal, {a, b}], True][[1]]   
(*0.089*)

RepeatedTiming@
 Position[Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, 
     Dimensions[a][[2]]], 0, 1][[1]]
(*0.0057*)
```

Comment: That's perfect and very simple. I tried to do a similar thing but I guess I messed up the syntax or something. Indeed I didn't want any cross-checking, comparing like-for-like position is an important part of my problem. Thanks so much! I'll mark as the answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 11):

This should be rather fast for very long packed arrays of integers.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
b = {{2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {41, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}};
f2[a_,b_] := Position[Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[a][[2]]], 0, 1];

f2[a,b]
```

> {{2}, {4}}

More complicated but twice as fast (thanks to Carl Woll for the idea to use `1.` instead of `1` in the `ConstantArray`):

```
f3[a_, b_] := SparseArray[
    Unitize[
     Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[a][[2]]]],
    {Length[a]},
    1
    ]["NonzeroPositions"];

RandomSeed[12345];
{a, b} = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {2, 1000000, 3}];

r2 = f2[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r3 = f3[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 == r3
```

> 0.060
>
> 0.021
>
> True

Comment: Using `ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[a][[2]]]` is a bit faster

Comment: Thanks, @CarlWoll, that's very good thing to keep in mind!

Answer (score 11):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
b = {{2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {41, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}};

Pick[Range@Length@a, Total /@ Unitize[Subtract[a, b]], 0]
```

> {2,4}

Or using @Henrik's idea of using `Dot` in in the second argument of `Pick`:

```
Pick[Range @ Length @ a,  
  Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[a][[2]]], 0]
```

> {2, 4}

Answer (score 5):

If you need speed, you could use ugly compiled function:

```
equalPosInt2 = Last@Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}, {b, _Integer, 2}},
  Module[{result, dimA, dimB, n, m, eq},
    result = Internal`Bag@Most@{0};
    dimA = Dimensions@a;
    dimB = Dimensions@b;
    n = Min[Compile`GetElement[dimA, 1], Compile`GetElement[dimB, 1]];
    m = Min[Compile`GetElement[dimA, 2], Compile`GetElement[dimB, 2]];
    Do[
      eq = True;
      Do[
        If[Compile`GetElement[a, i, j] =!= Compile`GetElement[b, i, j],
          eq = False;
          Break[];
        ];
        ,
        {j, m}
      ];
      If[eq, Internal`StuffBag[result, i]];
      ,
      {i, n}
    ];
    Internal`BagPart[result, All]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Basic test:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
b = {{2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {41, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}};
equalPosInt2[a, b]
(* {2, 4} *)
```

Timings:

```
fraccalo[a_, b_] := Position[MapThread[Equal, {a, b}], True]
f2[a_, b_] := Position[Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[a][[2]]], 0, 1]
f3[a_, b_] := SparseArray[Unitize[Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[a][[2]]]], {Length[a]}, 1]["NonzeroPositions"]
kglr1[a_, b_] := Pick[Range@Length@a, Total /@ Unitize[Subtract[a, b]], 0]
kglr2[a_, b_] := Pick[Range@Length@a, Unitize[Subtract[a, b]].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[a][[2]]], 0]

RandomSeed@12345;
{a, b} = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {2, 1000000, 3}];

r1 = fraccalo[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming     (*{0.691, 280000672}*)
r2 = f2[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming           (*{0.0803, 64000928}*)
r3 = f3[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming           (*{0.048,  64001120}*)
r4 = kglr1[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming        (*{0.072,  56000904}*)
r5 = kglr2[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming        (*{0.0495, 72001232}*)
r6 = equalPosInt2[a, b]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.0054,    29928}*)

r1[[All, 1]] === r2[[All, 1]] === r3[[All, 1]] === r4 === r5 === r6
(* True *)
```